# Record count for day and next day from table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to find the count of records for day + 1 using below hive query. Getting error because We have hive 0.10 version.

```
select 
lead(count(*)) over (order by day),
day 
from device_fact_kpis 
where day=20160301 group 
by day;
```

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:27 missing FROM at '(' near '(' in
>   subquery source line 1:28 cannot recognize input near 'order' 'by'
>   'day' in subquery source

Is there a way to find count for next day without using lead function as hive 0.10 does not have lead function.

Answer (score 0):

Your query wouldn't work anyway, because you need to do the `lead()` *before* you filter by day.

In any case, you can use a CTE and a `join`:

```
with t as (
      select day, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      group by day
     )
select day, cnt, tnext.cnt as next_cnt
from t left join
     t tnext
     on tnext.day = date_add(t.day, 1);
```

EDIT:

The version without the CTE is very similar:

```
select day, cnt, tnext.cnt as next_cnt
from (select day, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      group by day
     ) t left join
     (select day, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      group by day
     ) tnext
     on tnext.day = date_add(t.day, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am getting below error using this query
hive> with t as (
    > select day, count(*) as cnt
    > from fact_vreclass_tickets t
    > where day=20160301
    > group by day
    > )
    > select day, cnt, tnext.cnt as next_cnt
    > from t left join
    > t tnext
    > on tnext.day = date_add(t.day, 1);
FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'with' 't' 'as'

Comment: Oy.  Your version doesn't even support CTEs?  You can do the same thing with two subqueries.

Comment: Windows functions were Introduced in Hive 0.11 while CTE in Hive 0.13.

Comment: Please suggest a way to solve this problem without using windows functions and CTE
Thanks